# Пояснительная конструкция

Tags: пунктуация

Необходимо ли обособить "Начало Руси. Славяне" тире с двух сторон? Выступает ли это как пояснительная конструкция?

*В первом цикле картин (?) "Начало Руси. Славяне" (?) художник выступает как один из зачинателей русского исторического пейзажа.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, обособлять название первого цикла картин не нужно, это обычное приложение, оформленное кавычками и относящееся к определяемому слову "цикл".

***В первом цикле картин "Начало Руси. Славяне"  художник выступает как один из зачинателей русского исторического пейзажа.***

Comment: _Екатерина: На мой взгляд, обособлять название первого цикла картин не нужно, это обычное приложение, оформленное кавычками и относящееся к определяемому слову "цикл"._ === Если всё так, как Вы говорите, то тогда каким членом предложения следовало бы считать слово "картин"?

Comment: И ещё: имелся ли у Рериха (помимо первого) **второй** цикл картин с таким же названием?

Comment: Почему с тем же названием? Весь этот первый цикл (серия) называется "Начало Руси. Славяне". Потом были гималайский, алтайский циклы. Рерих - многоранный мастер.

Comment: А что по поводу "картин"? (См. мой первый вопрос)

Comment: Несогласованное определение к слову цикл (картинный цикл), если подходить детально. Но можно сочетание "цикл картин" рассматривать как цельное и считать определяемым словосочетанием. Я обычно оговариваю оба варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Как-либо обособить надо. Это могут быть и тире, и скобки.

[§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119)

1. Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, выделяются (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире, двоеточием). Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами предложения заключается в том, что если уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому  [[см. § 22]](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_22.htm), то пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к двум предыдущим ответам хочу заметить, что в гуглокнигах можно найти подобным образом построенные фразы как с обособлением, так и без него. Думаю, что оба варианта допустимы, хотя вариант без обособления встречается чаще. Приведу для примера пару цитат:

> В своей первой книге «Воспоминания» я описал краткий период моей учебы
>   в кинотехникуме в г. Одесса в 1930-1933 гг. (музыковед Н.Д. Бернштейн)
>
> В своей последней книге, «Послесловие», он впервые датирует
>   большинство стихотворений... (филолог М. Гаспаров)